# Can you bet your last body?

Tags: c.a.t.s

I have been wondering about this, but I don't want to ruin my account with this experiment.

So, can I bet my last body(this box you are battling in)? If yes, what happens if I lose my bet? Will I be unable to play until I unlock a supply box or sponsor box? Will I be battling with levitating weapons and wheels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this review](https://www.commonsensemedia.org/app-reviews/cats-crash-arena-turbo-stars), you can only bet spare parts, not the one you are using. This is likely to prevent not having parts.

> But there's betting, though you only bet spare parts.